# Qualifier errors when attempting to debug, along with final lines -- help pls

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the code i have put together from various examples to try achieve my goal. Concept is to be dynamic and retrieve from survey sheet within my workbook, to be able to obtain the corresponding TVD for the MD
--Use while loop only to run code if there is a depth in Column B Present. Nested loop uses the difference between depths to calculate a gradient. 
---The issue i'm having is getting past my first debug error "Invalid Qualifier".
----Lastly, any suggestions for how i would then return the TVD to Column A, relevant to the looked up MD, within the nested loop to maintain the row in which the MD was grabbed. Sorry for making this so wordy, been working on this for over 10hrs while at work.

http://www.wellog.com/tvd.htm

```
Sub MdtoTVD()

Dim MD1 As String, MD2 As Integer
Dim TVD1 As String, TVD2 As Integer
Dim Srng As Range 'Survey MD column
Dim MDrng As Range 'MdtoTVD MD column as range
Dim MDdiff As Integer ' Var to calculate difference of MD end from MD start
Dim TVDdiff As Integer ' Var to calculate difference of TVD end from TVD start
Dim TVDincr As Double ' var to use for stepping TVD
Dim MDrow As Integer
Dim i As Long

MDrng = Range("Surveys!B27:B215") 'range from the survey sheet within my report book
Srng = Range("Surveys!G27:G215") 'range from the survey sheet within my report book



Dim X As Integer
X = 2
While Not (IsEmpty(Sheets("MDtoTVD").Cells(X, 2).Value)) 'runs loop as long as there a MD depth to be looked up
Cells(X, 2) = MDrow 'assigns current row value to for MD input
MD1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Srng, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(MDrow, MDrng, 1)) ' retrieves Start point for MD
MD2.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Srng, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(MDrow, MDrng, 1) + 1) 'retrieves end point for MD
TVD1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(MDrng, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(MDrow, Srng, 1)) 'retrieves start point for TVD
TVD2.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(MDrng, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(MDrow, Srng, 1) + 1) 'retrieves end point for TVD
MDdiff.Value = (MD2 - MD1) 'assigns and calculates difference of MD end from MD start
TVDdiff.Value = (TVD2 - TD1) 'assigns and calculates difference of TVD end from TVD start
TVDincr.Value = MDdiff / TVDdiff 'Divides MD by TVD to get increment per foot

For i = 1 To MDdiff Step TVDincr 'set max loop run to amount of feet between survey points
Cells(X, 1).Value = TVD1 + i 'uses the loop to increment the TVD from start point
Next i

Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a number of problems with your code:

1. `MD1`, `MD2`, `TVD1`, `TVD2` are all of type `String`. Also, `MDdiff`, `TVDdiff` and `TVDIncr` are all of type `Integer`. The property `Value` is not defined for a string or integer variable. Just remove the `.Value` from all of them and you won't get the `"Invalid Qualifier"` error.
2. After you do the above, the following lines will give another error about type mismatch:

   ```
   MDdiff = (MD2 - MD1)
   TVDdiff = (TVD2 - TD1)
   ```

   because you're trying to subtract a string from another string and assign the result to an integer. Not sure what to advise there, you have to consider what you're trying to achieve and act accordingly. Maybe they shouldn't be strings in the first place? I don't know, up to you to determine that.

   At the very least, you can cast strings to integers if you're really sure they're string representations of integers by doing `CInt(string_var)` or use `CLng` to convert to long. If the strings are not string representations of integers and you try to cast them to integers, you'll get a type mismatch error.
3. When you assign a value to a `Range` object, you need to use `Set`. So do:

   ```
   Set MDrng = Range("Surveys!B27:B215")
   Set Srng = Range("Surveys!G27:G215")
   ```

   to correctly set the ranges.
4. Another problem is that you haven't assign a value to `X` but you use it as a cell index. By default, uninitialised numeric variables in VBA get assigned the value of `0`, so doing `.Cells(X, 2)` will fail because `row 0` is not a valid row index.
5. In this line:

   ```
   TVDincr = MDdiff / TVDdiff
   ```

   you're dividing two integers and you assign the result to another integer. Note that if the result of the division happens to be a decimal (like `3 / 2 = 1.5`), your `TVDincr` integer will actually contain just `1`, i.e. you lose some precision. I don't understand your code to know if it's ok or not, you have to judge for yourself, I'm pointing it out just in case you're not aware of that.

   Also, if `TVDdiff` happens to be `0`, then you'll get a "division by zero" error.
6. This line in your `For` loop:

   ```
   Cells(X, 1).Value = TVD1 + i
   ```

   will also generate an error, because you're trying to numerically add `TVD1` (a string) and `i` (a long). Perhaps you're trying to concatenate the two, in which case you should replace `+` with `&`.
7. There's also a problem when calling the `WorksheetFunction`s, but I haven't been able to determine the cause. Probably if you fix the other errors then it'll be easier to understand what's going on, not sure though. You just have to investigate things a little bit too.